# External RC oscillator fuse programmed instead of external crystal fuse

Tags: oscillator, atmega, crystal, avrdude, fuse-bits

Is there anyway to revive an Atmega8A? `avrdude` says `avrdude: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1` ever since I programemd the fuse incorrectly. There is an external crystal and its two load caps on the board and it has worked with those in the recent past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the external RC oscillator mode, the oscillator block onboard the chip will not work with a crystal. You would need to connect a resistor and a capacitor as shown in app note [AVR051](https://up.dmf313.ir/Application-Note_Set-up-and-Use-the-External-RC-Oscillator.pdf):

[image]

If it's hard to disconnect the crystal (e.g. because the chip is already integrated onto a PCB), you may even be able to leave the crystal connected as long as the RC frequency is relatively small compared to the crystal frequency - this isn't the best setup, but it should get you far enough to fix the fuse bits as an emergency measure.

An alternative (if you have access to most of the AVR pins) is to use the HVPP mode of the microcontroller; you'll need a special programmer that can apply +12 V (!) to the RESET pin. An example of such a programmer is described [here](https://hackaday.com/2010/12/14/avr-hv-rescue-shield-2/). This also has the benefit of working even if the RESET pin has been disabled with bad fuse settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the crystal with an external 1..4MHz square wave generator at XTAL1. An Arduino output with a fast set_bit/clear_bit loop can provide this if you don't have a function generator at hand. Avrdude should be able to erase the chip and correct the fuses with that clock. I have recovered a lot of atmega88's that way.

Comment: Did this really work in the exact same scenario, where the ATmega is configured to use an external RC network instead of an oscillator?

Comment: @SimSon: The resulting internal clock iss a mess in this case, the internal sink driver sometimes wins an edge, but the cpu has a static design and the charge pump for chip erase or at least fuse erase seems to reach the needed voltage. I used this in 5V context with atMega88 and atMega168, didn't try with 3.3V.

Comment: then that's a great alternative to a high-voltage programmer, which the typical Arduino user doesn't have.